# How to parse XML correctly by specifying the parent of the subcategories?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Faced with such a problem. It is necessary to pair categories with subcategories genres from liters, I want to do this through a simple function without bicycles. At this [link](https://partnersdnld.litres.ru/genres_list_2/), the generated XML with genres, which needs to be parsed by substituting the id attribute as the parent to the child sections.

There is such an XML structure:

```
<genres>
        <genre id="5003" title="бизнес-книги" type="root">
                <genre id="5049" title="банковское дело" token="bankovskoe_delo" type="genre"/>
                <genre id="210646" title="бизнес-справочники" token="business-spravochniki" type="genre"/>
                <genre id="5051" title="бухучет / налогообложение / аудит" token="buhuchet_nalogooblozhenie_audit" type="genre"/>
                <genre id="6784" title="государственное и муниципальное управление" token="gosudarstvennoe_i_munitsipalnoe_upravlenie" type="genre"/>
                <genre id="5060" title="делопроизводство" token="deloproizvodstvo" type="genre"/>
                <genre id="5061" title="зарубежная деловая литература" token="zarubezhnaya_delovaya_literatura" type="genre"/>
                <genre id="5062" title="интернет-бизнес" token="internet" type="genre"/>
                 <genre id="5047" title="кадровый менеджмент" token="kadrovyj_menedzhment" type="container">
                          <genre id="5334" title="аттестация персонала" token="attestaciya_personala" type="genre"/>
                          <genre id="5330" title="гендерные различия" token="gendernyye_razlichiya" type="genre"/>
                          <genre id="5332" title="конфликты" token="konflikty" type="genre"/>
                          <genre id="5336" title="коучинг" token="kouching" type="genre"/>
                          <genre id="5333" title="мотивация" token="motivaciya" type="genre"/>
                          <genre id="5335" title="поиск и подбор персонала" token="poisk_presonala_hr" type="genre"/>
                          <genre id="5331" title="тимбилдинг" token="timbilding" type="genre"/>
                          <genre id="6583" title="управление персоналом" token="upravlenie_personalom" type="genre"/>
                 </genre>
...
</genres>
```

PHP Code:

```
$url = 'https://partnersdnld.litres.ru/genres_list_2/';

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

$dom->load($url);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//genre') as $node) {
    var_dump(
        [
            'parent_id' => $xpath->evaluate('string(ancestor::genre[1]/id)', $node),
            'id' => $xpath->evaluate('string(id)', $node),
            'title' => $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $node),
        ]
    );
}
```

And he got confused in the sections and attributes. Can someone tell me why it outputs empty results and how to parse parent_id and the rest of the data correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes are on a different Xpath axis. `id` is short for `child::id` and will fetch the element node on the child axis. For the attribute axis use `attribute::id` or the shortcut `@id`.

Additionally to fetch the attribute from the context node I would suggest using the DOM method. No need for Xpath in this case:

```php
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//genre') as $node) {
    var_dump(
        [
            'parent_id' => $xpath->evaluate('string(ancestor::genre[1]/@id)', $node),
            'id' => $node->getAttribute('id'),
            'title' => $node->getAttribute('title'),
        ]
    );
}
```